Compiler wrongfully regards variable as rvalue
For some reason GCC regards variable a as an rvalue within the initialization of variable b (of which the expression is of type int&). And, as a result, rejects the code as it's not able to bind a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue. Is this simply a compiler bug of GCC or does this expression somehow violates the C++20 standard?
int a{}, b = decltype((a)){a}; // gcc: can't bind non-const lvalue ref to rvalue

Demo

Re: "variable b—which is of type int&" - No, b is not an int&. It's an int. The above would be similar to using T = int&; int a{}, b; b = T{a};.

Yes, looks like a bug.

@TedLyngmo It's an awkward sentence, OP probably meant to say "within the initialization of b, the variable a is deduced to have type int&". Which isn't exactly correct, but the gist is: decltype((a)) is int&.

@PasserBy Yes, something is probably wrong in that sentence. It'd be good if OP could clear it up.

gcc works without the extra brackets in decltype: https://godbolt.org/z/W5vnxzs1q

@AlanBirtles Yeah, but that makes it a plain int instead of an int&. gcc refuses this too: using T = int&; int a{}, b = T{a}; but clang and MSVC accepts it.

@TedLyngmo does it accept int a{}; using T=decltype((a)); T bb{a};? I want to test reference init with braces.

@Red.Wave Sure, but that's a very different case. It's the same as int a{}; int& bb{a};

@TedLyngmo I'm just curious about the extent of the problem. Obviously SB(not me) is supposed to file a bug report.

I guessed maybe {a} is regarded as a copy, regardless of context. So, I wanted to confirm whether or not that's the case.

@Red.Wave :) I usually file a bug report if I'm close to sure it's a bug. Here I'm only ~75% sure  :-) In the case decltype((a)){a} I'm assuming gcc materializes a temporary int& and that's were it goes awry. It has no problem with using T = int&&; int b = T{a}; but then clang complains

@TedLyngmo what about using T= int&?

@Red.Wave That's the same as decltype((a)) like I showed in the first comment, but with T = int both gcc and clang elides instantiation of the temporary as they should. With T = int&& gcc compiles it but it creates a temporary (so there are 3 instances created in total). Assuming that happens for T = int& too, it sort of explains the error. I'm unsure if it's correct to create a temporary there but perhaps it is. I'm down to 50% sure now :-)

So my guess holds. gcc wrongfully(?) treats {a} as a copy, disregarding the context.

@TedLyngmo Thanks for pointing that out. I tried to clear it up a little bit, but feel to word it differently if you have a better way of phrasing it.

This is arguably a GCC bug, and arguably a known defect CWG 1521. I have submitted a report at GCC Bug 115085.
Firstly, let's be clear about what this code should be treated as:
int a{}, b = decltype((a)){a};

a is being value-initialized, and b (of type int) is being copy-initialized using postfix-expression consisting of a decltype((a)) simple-type-specifier and {a} within a braced-init-list.
a is an unqualified-id which is not move-eligible, and because a is a a variable, a is an lvalue.
Whether a appears within decltype or within braces is not relevant; it should be an lvalue in either case.
Therefore, decltype((a)) is int& (which all compilers seem to get right), but considering a to be an rvalue within braces is wrong.
However, b = decltype((a)){a} is defective as a whole.
[expr.type.conv] p2 states that the initializer should be a prvalue in this case, but this is impossible/nonsensical for reference types.
This issue is a long-standing defect CWG 1521.
Some more bug investigation
Note that all compilers accept the following code:
int a{}, b = decltype((a))(a);

This makes sense because the use of direct-list-initialization shouldn't have an effect here, and both (a) and {a} should work the same.
Perhaps the bug is caused by GCC thinking that {a} is somehow aggregate-initialization, where each member is copy-initialized, and by some mechanism, prvalues emerge.
Another possible explanation is that we are doing copy-initialization of b, and a is being turned into an rvalue by lvalue-to-rvalue conversion/temporary materialization, and this happens too early, i.e. before the reference binding can happen.
All compilers also accept this code (as they should):
int a{}, &b{a};

This time, b is simply a reference which is direct-list-initialized using the lvalue a.

Dealing with the wording issues now at https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/536

Also mentioned in this old answer
